# Understanding the nature of merge in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to understand the `pd.merge` work nature. I have two dataframes that have unequal length. When trying to merge them through this command

```
merged = pd.merge(surgical, comps[comps_ls+['mrn','Admission']], on=['mrn','Admission'], how='left')
```

The length was different from expected as follows

```
length of comps: 4829
length of surgical: 7939
length of merged: 9531
```

From my own understanding, `merged` dataframe should have as same as the length of `comps` dataframe since `left` join will look for matching keys in both dataframes and discard the rest. As long as `comps` length is less than `surgical` length, the `merged` length should be 4829. Why does it have 9531?? larger number than the length of both. Even if I changed the `how` parameter to `"right"`, `merged` has a larger number than expected.

Generally, I want to know how to merge two dataframes that have unequal length specifying some columns from the right dataframe. Also, how do I validate the merge operation?. Find this might be helpful:

```
comps_ls: list of complications I want to throw on surgical dataframe.
mrn, Admission: the key columns I want to merge the two dataframes on.
```

Note: a teammate suggests this solution

```
merged = pd.merge(surgical, comps[comps_ls+['mrn','Admission']], on=['mrn','Admission'], how='left')
merged = surgical.join(merged, on=['mrn'], how='left', lsuffix="", rsuffix="_r")
```

The length of the output was as follows

```
length of comps: 4829
length of surgical: 7939
length of merged: 7939
```

How can this help?

Comment: It means that for a unique `('mrn', 'Admission')` , the right dataframe (`surgical`) has multiple entries, and they are all selected during the merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "issue" is with duplicated merge keys, which can cause the resulting merge to be larger than the original. For a left merge you can expect the result to be in between `N_rows_left` and `N_rows_left * N_rows_right` rows long. The lower bound is in the case that both the left and right DataFrames have no duplicate merge keys, and the upper bound is the case when the left and right DataFrames have the single same value for the merge keys on every row.

Here's a worked example. All DataFrames are 4 rows long, but `df2` has duplicate merge keys. As a result when `df2` is merged to `df` the output is longer than `df`, because for the row with `2` as the key in df, **both** rows in `df2` are matched.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': [1,2,3,4]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'row': range(4), 'key': [2,3,4,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'row': range(4), 'key': [2,2,3,3]})

# Neither frame duplicated on merge key, result is same length (4) as left. 
df.merge(df1, on='key', how='left')

#   key  row
#0    1  NaN
#1    2  0.0
#2    3  1.0
#3    4  2.0


# df2 is duplicated on the merge keys so we get >4 rows 
df.merge(df2, on='key', how='left')

#   key  row
#0    1  NaN
#1    2  0.0    # Both `2` rows matched
#2    2  1.0    # ^
#3    3  2.0    # Both `3` rows matched
#4    3  3.0    # ^
#5    4  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

If the length of the merged dataframe is greater than the length of the left dataframe, it means that the right dataframe has multiple entries for the same joining key. For instance if you have these dataframes:

```
df1
---
    id      product
0   111     car
1   222     bike
```

```
df2
---
    id      color
0   111     blue
1   222     red
3   222     green
3   333     yellow
```

A merge will render 3 rows, because there are two possible matches for the row of `df1` with id `222`.

```
df1.merge(df2, on="id", how="left")
---
    id      product  color
0   111     car      blue
1   222     bike     red
2   222     bike     green
```